# Does Ubuntu Phone SDK support 12.04?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I'm excited about Ubuntu Phone supporting QML, and i'm wondering if the SDK supports 12.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the packages are available for 12.04. Follow the instructions at http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/ and you will get them all.